# Как сокращать текст в абзаце?

Tags: javascript, html, css

чтобы не вылазило за пределы ссылки

```css
a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 60px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<a>
  <p class="name">testtesttesttest</p>&nbsp;<span>(en)</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Сокращать именно? Всмысле показывать многотчие? Или имеете ввиду чтобы текст на следующую строку переходил? Или что-то другое вообще имеется ввиду?

Comment: @EzioMercer, многотчие

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[text-overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)

```css
a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 60px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

a > p {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 100%;
  
}
```

```html
<a>
  <p class="name">testtesttesttest</p>&nbsp;<span>(en)</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Даже не знал, что есть такое св-во :) Хоть и вопрос не мой, но спасибо за новые знания)